# Android WebView web page does not fit the whole screen????

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

Okay I have a webView which loads a web page.  The web view fits the screen at first for like 2 seconds after it starts loading but then suddenly the text no longer wraps.  But when I zoom in and then zoom back out it wraps again and stays that way.  I want it to do that automatically.  I have tried to fix this issue with setInitialScale() and setUseWidePort(true) both have failed to solve the issue.  Surprisingly the same website works fine on the phone browser no problem.Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try setInitialScale(1)? What number did you put in the parameter?

You could also try to set the width to 0dp, and then make the layout_weight="1" (if this is in a linearlayout)

Comment: I did try that I tried a wide variety of parameters they all failed, and this is a RelativeLayout sorry should have included that.